# Is there a way to turn off the paypal checkout button in /cart view in drupal 7 commerce?

Tags: 7, payment-gateways, commerce

After adding an item to the cart in drupal 7 commerce, the /cart page has a **checkout with paypal** button. Is there a way to remove this in the commerce payment configuration pages? It seems unnecessary and confusing. I know I can hide it via css, but was wondering if there was a option somewhere.

[image]

Comment: What module are you using to provide that button?

Comment: just using commerce_paypal ..

Comment: That's not provided by the commerce PayPal module. I have many sites running it and have never seen that before. It must be provided by something else. Maybe https://drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal_ec

Comment: @NigelWaters That could be an answer, although I am not sure this question is not too localized.

Comment: Yea it seems to be commerce_paypal_ec -- express checkout...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This button comes from the Express Checkout module in the Commerce PayPal project. If you don't need Express Checkout, just uninstall that module. If you do, it's a functional requirement of PayPal for the button to be present here. However, I will go open a feature request now to turn that into an area handler for Order Views. Makes sense and would do what you're asking.

Comment: Wait, so paypal requires the button to be present on that step or it's one of the modules non-configurable features? Which paypal module provides the same functionality later in the checkout process?

Comment: The same module handles both the "shortcut" flow (which is the button at /cart) and the "mark" flow (which is the payment option on the checkout form). If you don't want it on /cart for now, you can use hook_form_alter() to remove it or potentially hook_module_implements_alter() to prevent it from being added in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

If found a simple way to disable the button through rules.

Edit the configuration of the Paypal EC payment method and add a condition to the rule:

Data Comparison / Commerce Order...state / Equal to 'Checkout'

In this way, when the order is still in Shopping Cart state the payment method is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not recommended, you can comment these lines:

```
$form['paypal_ec'] = array(
 '#type' => 'image_button',
 '#value' => t('Check out with PayPal'),
 '#src' => commerce_paypal_ec_button_url(),
 '#attached' => array(
   'css' => array(
     drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_paypal_ec') . '/theme/commerce_paypal_ec.theme.css',
   ),
 ),
);
```

Comment: Altering the paypal_ec  paypal form maybe a an option. But please, not inside the module itself.  Better to go for a much safer [hook_form alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x)