# How would a customer be able to get free shipping when there are no free shipping options?

Tags: commerce, rules

We just launched our ecommerce store using Drupal Commerce Kickstart, which heavily uses Rules to manage shipping.

We have had two orders from the same Virginia-based customer. Both orders were processed without shipping applied. When I select the same items, enter the same Virginia USA shipping address and go through the checkout process, I get the expected behavior of Standard Shipping - $15 being applied. I cannot replicate the behavior.

The checkout process / sequence is as follows.

[image: Checkout Process Map]

The "Standard Shipping - Domestic" rule is called for:

1. Addresses within the "US"
2. Orders not contain three Product Categories (bikes, wheels, forks)

*The order in question does not contain these items.

[image: Rules View / Shipping Configuration]

I attempted to duplicate in both Chrome Incognito & Firefox. No issues on my side. I see the following:

1. One option to select from under "Shipping"
   [image: Shipping Selection]
2. Shipping applied under "Review Order"
   [image: Review Order Showing Shipping]
3. When viewing in admin mode, I see shipping applied as a line item on the order.
   [image: Test Order - detail]
   PLUS - The correct sequence is maintained
   [image]

When I view the customer order, there is no shipping line item. 
[image: Customer Invoice Summary]

AND the customer appears to be going through a different order sequence and bypasses the Shipping selection. How is this possible? I am totally confused.
[image: Customer Checkout Process History]

How is it possible to bypass the checkout sequence in Commerce Kickstart?
1. Test: Checkout > Shipping > Review Order
2. User: Create order > Add item to cart > Pending (Which is typically after the order is fully paid. We have confirmed that payment has been received.)

Very curious. Curiouser & curiouser.

Comment: New info: I had enabled "PayPal Express Checkout. When the user goes to "View Cart", they bypass the standard checkout process. Shoot. Now I need to figure out how to apply the shipping rules through Paypal express checkout.

Comment: Looks like same issue as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913338/paypal-express-checkout-completes-without-adding-shipping

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77167/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-the-paypal-checkout-button-in-cart-view-in-drupal-7

Edit the configuration of the Paypal EC payment method and add a condition to the rule:

Data Comparison / Commerce Order...state / Equal to 'Checkout'

In this way, when the order is still in Shopping Cart state the payment method is disabled.

shareedit
answered Aug 11 '15 at 18:17

Zachary
16419

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that shipping selection needs to happen for Express Checkout users, then if you edit the Express Checkout module's order confirmation checkout pane you can choose which checkout panes from other pages should appear on the final confirmation page. Make sure you check the box there for shipping service selection and it should show up as expected.